# Job / Run Loop manager for embedded device?

Tags: mqtt, linux, zeromq

I'm in process of creating an IoT Prototype which runs (currently) on ARM processor with Embedded Linux. I'm trying to use existing technologies as much as possible: for example MQTT for external communication and ZeroMQ for IPC communication. Now I want to have defined routines, for example read data from sensor and call them cyclically, when interval is configured. In other words I want to have something which takes over the required functionality:  configure callbacks (threads), configure call intervals, manage scheduled execution.

Is there any existing library / framework for that?

Comment: What development board are you using and how are you using it? Which particular flavor of Linux are you using? What development language are you using? Please update your posted question with more details.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, then you might consider asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/